# "Level Стрешнево — лучшая цена за м²!" Именительный темы?

Tags: синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор, именительный-темы

Вот пример встретившейся рекламы:

> Level Стрешнево — лучшая цена за м²!

Level Стрешнево — это именительный темы? Или это всё эллиптическое предложение?
Допустима ли в случае именительного темы такая пунктуация?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***ЖК Level Стрешнево — лучшая цена за м²!***

Пояснение к названию. Застройщик «Level Group»  строит в Москве несколько жилых комплексов: Level Стрешнево, Level Амурская, Level Донской, Level Павелецкая.

А предложение обычное двусоставное, оно построено по схеме **предмет — его характеристика**. В данном случае это характеристика по цене.

У Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=92#pp92

1. Тире ставится между подлежащим и сказуемым при отсутствии связки, если оба главных члена предложения выражены существительными в форме именительного падежа.  Как правило, тире ставится:

2) в предложениях книжных стилей (научного, публицистического, официально-делового), содержащих характеристику, **оценку предмета или явления**:  Разоружение — веление времени;

А что касается **современного определения** предложения, то в общем смысле оно "семантически всегда **соотносит друг с другом** два каких-то понятия..."

Важно именно это: в предложении **две номинации соотнесены семантически**, отнесены к реальности. С этой точки зрения именительный темы — это как бы **изолированная номинация**.  Например: *Level Стрешнево! Только у нас лучшая цена за м²!*

Предложение можно представить как **эллиптическое** по  схеме обстоятельство — подлежащее: *В Level Стрешнево — лучшая цена за м²!*

Comment: Спасибо! "Пояснение к названию." — это конструкция, не являющаяся предложением, характеризующая последующий текст, но оформленное как предложение?

Answer (score 0):

Это не является эллиптическим предложением, так как в нем все главные члены предложения на месте.

**Level-цена** — это именительный темы.

Пример именительного темы:

> Урал! Завет веков и вместе — предвестье будущих времен, и в наши души, точно песня, могучим басом входит он!

Comment: А кого вы цитируете?

Comment: Дайте пример, пожалуйста,  именительного темы, чтоб было с чем сравнить.

Comment: Разве «Level-цена» не придумка?

Comment: @Cloud перед подобными советами вам стоило бы хотя бы поинтересоваться, что «Level Стрешнево» это название ЖК. Да и сам совет, мягко говоря, странный. На львиную долю наш язык состоит из заимствований. Или будете настаивать, что употребляемое вами определение "эллиптическое предложение" — исконно наше выражение?